# Google Directions API error

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api, map-directions

When I use the following url:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Cais%20do%20Sodre&destination=Gare%20do%20Oriente&sensor=false&mode=transit
```

I'm getting the result

```
{
"routes" : [],
"status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

but it works on google maps. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [transit mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes) in a directions request, there are additional *required* [parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters):

> **Either the arrival_time or the departure_time parameter must be specified any time you request transit directions.**

This returns a response for me:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Cais%20do%20Sodre&destination=Gare%20do%20Oriente&sensor=false&mode=transit&arrival_time=12
```